# different OpenGL ES vertex color interpolation modes?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to implement a simple linear gradient like in photoshop. The color interpolation between vertices seems to go by (additive?)numerical value rather than what you would expect in "paint blending." Here is a visual example with green and red:

[image: Gradient1][image: Gradient2]

The one on the left is roughly what I get, and I want to achieve the one on the right.

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Comment: If you drop OpenGL ES from your list of APIs, you will have a lot more capability for this sort of thing. ES *always* smoothly interpolates vertex attributes during rasterization. Desktop GL can be configured to do no interpolation, coupled with a geometry shader you can do some pretty advanced interpolation on your own.

Comment: That said, if you want a linear gradient there are ***much*** simpler and more portable ways of doing this. A 1D ramp texture will work beautifully for that purpose.

Comment: Hi Andon, the 1d ramp texture seems like a great idea. Would I do it by assigning a 1d texture coord to each vertex? I'm new to OpenGL so any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: So I have to say that the yellow result is actually an error on my part. My actual result was not really a gradient, more like a yellow band. This was curious result of my passing unsigned byte colors instead of clamped float colors. OpenGL color interpolation actually works just like the right picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Andon commented, using the texture system is a good way to do this. Here's what you need:

1. Assign one (or more, but you only need one for this trick) texture coordinate(s) to each vertex when you set up attributes in your vertex buffer.
2. In your vertex shader, read that attribute and write it to a varying so it gets interpolated for use in the fragment shader.
3. In your fragment shader, read the varying -- this tells you how far along the gradient ramp you should be in the current fragment; i.e. a blending factor.

At this point, you have two choices:

- Use a 1d texture image that looks like the gradient you want, and lookup into it with the `texture2D` shader function and the varying texture coordinate you got. This will fetch the corresponding texel color so you can output it to `gl_FragColor`.
- Calculate the color blend in the fragment shader. If you pass in the endpoint colors in your shader as uniforms, you combine them according to the blending factor using whatever math you can do in GLSL (including things like [Photoshop blend modes](http://renderingpipeline.com/2012/06/photoshop-blendmodi-glsl/)).

Comment: I'm inclined to go with the second approach since I need more flexibility with the colors. I also read about the texture1D function. Is it applicable in the first approach?

Comment: also, I would give another +1 for photoshop blend mode formulas